# Take the first half of a byte

Tags: c#, byte

I'm looking for a more performant/elegant way to taking the first 4 bits of a bytes. The bytes are in big endian

```
var gpsFixStatus = (int)raw[28];
int[] remainder = new int[8];
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    remainder[i] = gpsFixStatus % 2;
    gpsFixStatus = gpsFixStatus / 2;
}
var gpsFix = byte.Parse((remainder[7].ToString() + remainder[6].ToString() + remainder[5].ToString() + remainder[4].ToString()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first half of byte `b` is

```
b >> 4
```

assuming you want it shifted into the lower four bits. If you want it still in place, but removing the bottom half, it's just

```
b & 240  // or "b & 0xf0"
```

But it looks from your code as though the former is what you want.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. raw[28] >> 4 does what I need. Thanks

Comment: @Jesse Note: I've just edited it fractionally. Really you want the `>>>` version, which puts a zero in the right-most bits. The `>>` version replicates the sign bit, so if you start with a signed type and a negative integer, you'll get ones in the most significant bits when you shift.

Comment: The compiler does not seem to like >>>

Comment: @Jesse Is this Java? That was my guess, but it would be useful to tag the post with a particular language.

Comment: @Jesse Perhaps it's VB? In which case `>>` is what you want: a `Byte` is unsigned in VB, so it puts zeros in the MSBs.

Comment: C# my apologizes , will tag